# fwrite 's paragram filename cause error Permission denied

Tags: php, file-io

my code:

```
$ffff = fopen("quce/1459412934LxKWY.", 'w');
fwrite($ffff, 'test');
fclose($ffff);
```

and the build result:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(quce/1459412934LxKWY.): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied

Comment: You just have to give permisions to that file (chmod). Or folder if thats the problem.

Comment: I have tried, but the same it run. I think its caused by hte paragram filename, i run on Windows.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a file with a name that ends with a dot in the first place? (If you tried that in Windows Explorer, it would just remove this trailing dot anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be a result of having SELinux enabled. This can be solved using:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/directory_to_write
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write
```

You can find more about the contexts at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html